# JabRef and BibTex

Tags: bibtex, jabref

So I am wondering how I can use german umlaute. Atm I get an utf8 inputenc error.
I tried to add:
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
but it didnt work...
Any suggestions?

Comment: Be  more explicit! If you want to use accented letters, you should consider using `biber` rather than `bibtex`.

Comment: I have lettes like ä,ü,ö in my literature which apparently isnt allowed? What is Biber?

Comment: A replacement for bibtex, that is utf8-aware. It works with `biblatex`. Biblatex can work with bibtex, but all its features will be used with biber.

Comment: Can u maybe make an example of how to use it?
ATM I dont have any \usepackage für that...I just write my stuff in JabRef and at the beginngin I say
\bibliographystyle{alphadin}
and at the end of the document say:
\bibliography{literatur}
Thats all. So what in addition do I have to do with Biber?

Comment: What are your distribution and TeX editor?

Comment: Miktex 2.9 and Texniccenter 2.0 is what u want to know?

Comment: Go to the TeXnicCenter `Build > Select Output Profile` and select `LATEX => PDF (BIBER)`, that's all.